# Prove by strong induction that $9^n$ ends in $1$ if $n$ is even and ends in $9$ if $n$ is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Prove by strong induction that $9^n$ ends in $1$ if $n$ is even and ends in $9$ if $n$ is odd.

Would it be valid to work separately with even and odd exponents, making two separate proofs, each using weak induction?

How can I prove this using strong induction in one proof?

Comment: Can you see why it's true intuitively? For example, if I give you a number that I claimed was some odd power of $9$, e.g. $31381059609$, can you see why, if you multiply this number by $9$, you'll end up with a final digit of $1$, without multiplying out the entire number?

Comment: Good! And I'm guessing you understand why a number ending in $1$, after multiplying by $9$, will end in $9$. So, am I right in thinking that this is purely about how to write up a strong induction proof of this fact?

Comment: Two base cases, $n=1$ and $n=2.$  Suppose our proposition is true for all $n\le k.$ This assumption makes for strong induction.  Then evaluate $n=k+1$ and $k+2$, based on the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Base cases: $$9^1=9, 9^2=81$$

Inductive step:

Assume that $9^k$ ends in 1 if k is even and 9 if k is odd for all k from 1 to n. (This is strong induction.) Consider $9^{n+1}$. This can be rewritten $9(9^n)$. If n is odd, then $9^n$ ends in 9 and the product ends in 1. That is, $9^{n+1}$ ends in 1 if n+1 is even. If n is even, then $9^n$ ends in 1 and the product ends in 9. That is, $9^{n+1}$ ends in 9 if n+1 is odd.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a perfectly valid induction proof, but isn't essentially a strong induction proof, as it never makes use of the assumptions about $9^k$ for any $k < n$. The induction step is proven by cases, and is a perfectly sensible way of going about it. +1

Comment: For OP, if $9^{n+1}$ you could write as $9^{n-1}9^2$. $9^2$ ends in 1 so the whole thing will end in whatever $9^{n-1}$ ends in. If n+1 is even, then n-1 is even, so it ends in 1 (by strong induction assumption) and the whole thing ends in 1. If n+1 is odd, then n-1 is odd, so by strong induction the whole thing ends in 9.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have three options.

1. You can prove if $9^{2k}$ ends with $1$, then $9^{2k+2}$ also ends with $1$; and then prove if $9^{2k-1}$ ends with $9$ then $9^{2k+1}$ also ends with $9$

or

2. You can prove if $9^n$ ends with $1$ then $9^{n+1}$ ends with $9$; and then prove if $9^{n}$ ends with $9$ then $9^{n+1}$ ends with $1$.
3. You can prove if $9^n$ ends with *whatever*, then $9^{n+2}$ also ends with *whatever*

Those are all very easy proves.

And 1) and 3) can be proven by noting $9^{n+2} = 9^n\cdot 9^2 = 9^n\cdot 81 = (10something + whatever)\times (80 + 1)= 800something + (80whatever + 10something) + whatever$.

And 2) can proven that $9^{n+1} = 9^n\cdot 9 = 9(10something + \begin{cases}1\\9\end{cases}) = 90something + \begin{cases}9\\81\end{cases})$.